# Javascript Element.ClassName always returning true on mousewheel change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scroll wheel function that changes the class of a div as you scroll down or up.

It is actually functioning really well in all modern browsers, the thing is, it is trying to change the class everytime it is executing, even though I have a validation that should stop this from happening.

The function asks that if the div already has that class active then it should not change, but if you look at the console it is trying to do it every time despite that validation.

I don't know why the className method always returns `true`.

I used jquery's `hasClass` function and had the same behavior.

Thank you so much for your help.

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
var sections = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];

function changeSection(section) {
  for (var x = 0; x < sections.length; x++) {
    $('#bg-main').removeClass('bg-' + sections[x]);
    if (sections[x] === section) {
      if (document.getElementById('bg-main').className != ('bg-' + section)) {
        $('#bg-main').addClass('bg-' + section);
        console.log("Active: " + section);
      } else {
        console.log("Inactive: " + sections[x]);
      }
    }
  }
}
var mousewheelevt = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel"
if (document.attachEvent)
  document.attachEvent("on" + mousewheelevt, displaywheel)
else if (document.addEventListener)
  document.addEventListener(mousewheelevt, displaywheel, false)
var position = 0;

function displaywheel(e) {
  var evt = window.event || e
  var delta = evt.detail ? evt.detail : evt.wheelDelta
  if (delta < 0) {
    position = (mousewheelevt == 'DOMMouseScroll') ? position - 1 : position + 1;
  } else {
    position = (mousewheelevt == 'DOMMouseScroll') ? position + 1 : position - 1;
  }

  if (position < 0) position = 0;
  if (position > 100) position = 100;

  // Change sections on Scroll
  if (position >= 0 && position <= 19) {
    changeSection('one');
  } else if (position >= 20 && position <= 39) {
    changeSection('two');
  } else if (position >= 40 && position <= 59) {
    changeSection('three');
  }
  if (position >= 60 && position <= 79) {
    changeSection('four');
  } else if (position >= 80 && position <= 100) {
    changeSection('five');
  }
}
```

CSS CODE:

```
#bg-main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.bg-one {
  background-color: blue;
}

.bg-two {
  background-color: red;
}

.bg-three {
  background-color: green;
}

.bg-four {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.bg-five {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="bg-main" class="bg-one">SCROLL TO SEE THE CHANGE OF BACKGROUND</div>
```

Working fidddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9vpuj582/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are removing the class before you check to see if the element has the class that you passed into your function (so your `if` statement will never evaluate as false).

The placement of the following line of code in your `changeSection` function is your issue:

```
$('#bg-main').removeClass('bg-'+sections[x]);
```

You could simplify your current function quite a bit. First check if the element already has the class you want. Then, if not, remove all classes from the element (rather than looping through them and checking each one) and then add the new class. For example:

```
const bg = $('#bg-main');
function changeSection(section) {
  if (!bg.hasClass('bg-' + section)) {
    bg.removeClass();
    bg.addClass('bg-' + section);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great solution, you are right. Had a logic problem removing the classes. Despite that your solution is better, Thank you.

Comment: Updated the fiddle with your solution and working as expected, Thank you.
https://jsfiddle.net/9vpuj582/4/